# Error handling in Rails Controller for adding embedded Mongoid documents to Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I have a Item model that has embedded documents.  Currently, the following comments_controller code will add a comment to the item successfully.  However, if pushing the comment document onto the comments array on item fails, I will not know this.

```
  #this does work, but i do not know if the push fails
  def create
    comment = Comment.new(:text => params[:text])
    @item.comments << comment
    render :text => comment
  end
```

I would like to have something like this, but @item.comments << comment does not return true or false:

```
  #this does not work
  def create
    comment = Comment.new(:text => params[:text])
    if @item.comments << comment
      render :text => comment
    else
      render :text => 'oh no'
    end
  end
```

Nor does it throw an exception when the document push fails:

```
  #this does not work
  def create
    begin
      comment = Comment.new(:text => params[:text])
      @item.comments << comment
      render :text => comment
    rescue Exception => e
      render :text => 'oh no'
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: weird, don't you need a `@item.save` after `@item.comments << comment` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the item for the comment, then persist it.  comment.save will return true if the save goes well and return false otherwise.  You can handle both scenarios as you see fit.

```
def create
  comment = Comment.new(:text => params[:text])
  comment.item = @item  
  if comment.save
    render :text => "yay"
  else
    render :text => "oh no"
  end
end
```